# mysql exclude query

Tags: mysql

I have a **wp_posts** and **wp_icl_translations** tables what are related to each other on **wp_posts.ID** and **wp_icl_translations.trid**. I want to exclude all those posts what already have translations.
The following  query is retrieving back all those rows what I actually want to exclude from.

```
SELECT  p.ID, 
        p.post_title 
 FROM   wp_posts AS p 
            JOIN wp_icl_translations AS  t
             ON p.ID= t.trid 
 WHERE p.post_type = '{$type}' AND 
       p.post_status = 'publish' AND 
       t.language_code='en' AND 
       t.element_type='post_post' 
ORDER BY post_title;
```

Comment: have you try with `LEFT JOIN`. by which column we define that transalation has been done already?

Comment: hi, thanks for the feedback t.language_code=en

Answer (score 1):

Use `LEFT JOIN` and select with `IS NULL`.

```
SELECT  p.ID, 
        p.post_title 
 FROM   wp_posts AS p 
 LEFT JOIN wp_icl_translations AS  t ON p.ID= t.trid 
 WHERE  p.post_type = '{$type}' AND 
        p.post_status = 'publish' AND 
        t.trid IS NULL
ORDER BY post_title;
```

Comment: i think only `IS NULL` will not satisfy OP. isn't it?

Comment: thanks, your query is returning my translated posts. What I want is to exclude those

Answer (score 0):

try ( not tested )

using NOT `<>` condition

```
SELECT p.ID,p.post_title 
FROM   wp_posts AS p 
INNER JOIN wp_icl_translations AS  t
             ON p.ID= t.trid 
WHERE p.post_type = '{$type}' AND 
       p.post_status = 'publish' AND 
       t.language_code <>'en' AND 
       t.element_type='post_post' 
ORDER BY post_title;
```

or

`LEFT JOIN` with `IS NULL`

```
SELECT p.ID,p.post_title 
FROM   wp_posts AS p 
LEFT JOIN wp_icl_translations AS  t
             ON p.ID= t.trid 
WHERE p.post_type = '{$type}' AND 
       p.post_status = 'publish' AND 
       t.trid IS NULL
ORDER BY post_title;
```

Comment: `t.trid IS NULL AND
       t.language_code <>'en' AND
       t.element_type='post_post'` will never be true.

Answer (score 0):

I would say something like this; using the (NOT) IN operator. But there might be a better solution (the performance of this shouldn't be that good, also it's not tested).

```
SELECT ID, 
       post_title 
FROM   wp_posts
WHERE  ID NOT IN 
(
      SELECT p.ID
      FROM   wp_posts AS p 
      JOIN   wp_icl_translations AS  t
        ON   p.ID= t.trid 
      WHERE  p.post_type = '{$type}' AND 
             p.post_status = 'publish' AND 
             t.language_code='en' AND 
             t.element_type='post_post' 

)
ORDER BY post_title;
```